# App not creating a sqlite database

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, ios6.1

For some reason, my app doesn't seem to create a database in the Documents folder. I have been following this video tutorial (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bC3F8a4F_KE) (it also has the source code available (https://github.com/iffytheperfect1983/sqliteTutorial) which I downloaded and it ran on the Simulator perfectly).

I used a few NSLog statements to attempt to pinpoint the problem. I realized that while all of the code up to "Declared" statement ran with no problems, the rest of the NSLog statements didn't show up in the console. I have looked tirelessly back and forth between the code I wrote and the code in the tutorial but with no avail for a solution.

Here is the code.

```
@interface ViewController () {

NSMutableArray *letterArray;
sqlite3 *letterDB;
NSString *dbPathString;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Set up
    letterArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [[self letterList] setDelegate:self];
    [[self letterList] setDataSource:self];
    // create or open database
    [self createOpenDB];

    // Display database
    [self displayDB];
}

// Create/open database
- (void) createOpenDB {
NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docPath = [path objectAtIndex:0];

dbPathString = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"letters.db"];

char *error;

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPathString]) {
    const char *dbPath = [dbPathString UTF8String];
    NSLog(@"Declared");
    // create database here
    if (sqlite3_open(dbPath, &lettersDB)==SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"'If' statement is ok");
        const char *sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LETTERS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, A TEXT, B TEXT, C TEXT, D TEXT, E TEXT, F TEXT, G TEXT)";
        NSLog(@"Declared");
        sqlite3_exec(lettersDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &error);
        NSLog(@"Execution complete.");
        sqlite3_close(lettersDB);
        NSLog(@"Close complete.");
        NSLog(@"Database creation successful.");
    }
}
}
```

How do I solve this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you run into such problems, check the error. Add an `else` to the `if` statement used to open the database. Log `sqlite_errmsg()`.

Comment: Thank you. I'll be sure to keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `NSDocumentationDirectory` when you should be using the `NSDocumentDirectory` directory.

Change this:

```
NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
```

To this:

```
NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
```

Comment: How could I have possibly missed that? I'm such an idiot. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You wouldn't have missed it if you'd checked for errors.  (Including nil returned for "not found".)

Comment: You're not an idiot. I've done this a bunch. Its a common mistake that is not helped by auto completion in Xcode.